# Linux implementation similar to Adaptec Intelligent Hybrid RAID?

Tags: linux, raid, cache

I could explain it in my bad english, but looking at this page is the fastest way:

http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/_common/hybrid-raid/

Do you know of any linux implementation for this outstanding feature? (to be so able to use it without the adaptec controller?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least [BCache](http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/) kernel patch for the brave souls; I have no idea if it's maintained, though. Any better suggestions are gladly welcome.

+1 for interesting question!

Comment: I also thought that Facebook's flashcache (https://github.com/facebook/flashcache) could be suited for this, while not exactly what i was hoping to find.
Thanks for the +1 and the answer ;)